# How to get the folder names present in the directory

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, io

I have a directory which is present at `@"F:\\Unzip\\"` .This directory will contain a folder.Now as per my requirement i want to move the folder inside it to some other directory but i am not able to get it.Here is the code that i tried to read the folder name present in the directory but it is reading the file present in the folder.

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"F:\\Unzip\\") == true)
{   
    //Get the file name

    List<String> files = Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\Unzip\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
    string strr=files[0].ToString();
}
```

Please help me to move the folder present inside the directory.Thanks

Comment: Move implies a source and a destination. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo[] dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomePath").GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(DirectoryInfo d in dir) 
{
    lst.Add(d.Name);
}
```

This will give you the list of all the folders in your directory.

Comment: @RadheyPandey:- I didnt understand that. Can you elaborate it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the names of subdirectories in the directory specified by "yourpath". The result is an array of strings.

```
Directory.GetDirectories("yourpath");
```

Easy as this:

```
string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\Unzip\","*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx

Comment: Can you please explain it a little?

Comment: Hope that this helps you

Comment: I think even my answer helps you :p

Answer (score 0):

`Directory.GetDirectories(@"F:\Unzip")` will yield a `string[]` of full paths to each directory in `F:\Unzip`

Answer (score 0):

read all directories without foreach loop using lambda

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
var allDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Github").GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();

lst = allDir;
```